# Matching dollar amount in REGEXP using egrep

Tags: regex, unix

Just wondering why this expression `egrep "\$[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9])?" dollar.txt` doesn't match $4.50, $5.00, $1000. It doesn't match anything similar, for that matter.

Also, the expression `egrep "\$" dollar.txt` matches

```
$1000 over here 

no money here
```

Can someone please explain why.
(Two parts to this question)...Thanks

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dNce.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match dollar amounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193403/regular-expression-to-match-dollar-amounts)

Comment: Perhaps because the example used is from the book "O'Reilly- Mastering Regular Expressions". Nonetheless, I have looked at the question and the answers still don't seem to give me a match.

Comment: That period `.` in your regexp is going to match any character at all, you know. I think you probably meant `\.`.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka my bad. Yes, I meant that. I have edited it now.

Comment: What happens if you change the double quotes to single quotes?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick changing it to single quotes seems to have worked. Thanks a lot. 
Based on Charles' answer, I guess it was because of bash interpreting  the the "$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying it on my machine, it appears that, even with the backslash in front of it, bash is interpreting the dollar sign `$`, along with whatever comes after it, as a variable to insert in the regex. Doing this seems to solve it, though:

`egrep "\Q$\E[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9])?" input`

EDIT: Using single quotes (suggested by @Mark Plotnick) seems to do the trick as well:

`egrep '\$[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9])?' input`